# Django jquery-ui autocomplete url changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using the jquery-ui autocomplete in an input. It works well for autocompleting but when I select the complete version of my input and hit enter, it goes to a link like `/?n=something` I want to change this link to `/baslik/something` it should go to `/baslik/something` for each input. 
I have these in my template file:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $( "input#n" ).autocomplete({
                            source: "{% url "autoco" %}",
                            minLength: 2
        });
});
</script>

<div class="ui-widget">
              <input id="n" type="text" name="n"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("n").addEventListener("change", function(){
    this.form.setAttribute("action", "/baslik/" + this.value);
  });
</script>
```

The last js part of the code above is transforming the input when user hits to enter to `/baslik/something` but it just does this if I do not change the input from autocomplete.

The view:

```
def autoco(request):
    term = request.GET.get('term')
    bslk = Baslik.objects.filter(title__istartswith=term)
    res = []
    for b in bslk:
         dict = {'id':b.id, 'label':b.__unicode__(), 'value':b.__unicode__()}
         res.append(dict)
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(res))
```

the url:

```
url(r'^autoco/$', autoco, name='autoco'),
```

How can I make this work in my way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution.
This is js part of jquery-ui autocomplete:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $( "input#n" ).autocomplete({
                            source: "{% url "autoco" %}",
                            minLength: 2,
                            select:function(e,ui) { 
      location.href = ui.item.the_link;
    //  console.log(ui.item.the_link);
}
        });
});

</script>
```

We added the_link attribute to it and we should describe it in our view:
this part:

```
dict = {'id':b.id, 'label':b.__unicode__(), 'value':b.__unicode__()}]
```

should be like this:

`dict = {'id':b.id, 'label':b.__unicode__(), 'value':b.__unicode__(), 'the_link':"baslik/"+b.__unicode__()}`